# How to count the total number of times a word appears using Microsoft Power Bi?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table that contains a list of words and I would like to know how I can use DAX to do the following example:

| ID | Items |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple |
| 2 | Banana |
| 3 | Apple, Banana |
| 4 | Orange, Apple |

| Items | Total |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | 3 |
| Banana | 2 |
| Orange | 1 |

The issue is some of the rows have more than one item and using Count only takes the first item on the list.

Output I don't want:

| Items | Total |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | 2 |
| Banana | 1 |
| Orange | 1 |

The current process I did was split the columns, use pivot, then do count.

Comment: You can create a separate table based on your source table where you will always have your item wise count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a separate table based on your source table where you will always have your item wise count. Use this below **Advanced Query** code for your new table.

Just change the source table name in the code with your original table name.

```
let
    Source = your_table_name,
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(Source, {{"Items", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Items"),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Items", type text}}),
    #"Trimmed Text" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type",{{"Items", Text.Trim, type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Trimmed Text", {"Items"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

Here is the final output-

[image]